# How do I most effectively generate Fury?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

Each of the Barbarian primary abilities generate "X Fury per attack". Fury is then used by the secondary abilities, and if you mash the right mouse button like me your beefy Man or woMan will soon be reminding you gruffly about his or her lack of *anger* with the minions of Hell.

Since it is essential to maintain my Barbarian's disgruntled state, what strategy can I use to best maximize Fury?  Does it only come down to each left mouse click?  Do I get more for hitting monsters in groups?  Does taking damage increase my rage?  Should I pattern my use of primary and secondary attacks (P+P+S, P+P+P+S, etc). What is the best strategy?

Comment: I like to pretend that the P's in your (P+P+S) construct stand for 'Pew-Pew'

Comment: They can if you'd like, but in a gruff manly voice. :)

Comment: This question overlaps with [a question about Wrath of the Berserker](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66327/what-is-a-good-build-to-maximize-the-time-you-spend-as-a-chaotic-berserker); there will be related advice there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your skill choices and the way that you are dealing your damage you may not need as much Fury as you think. Personally, most of my damage output comes from Cleave and I seldomly am spending fury anyway. However, if you find that your Fury is frequently low there are ways to beef up the generation. There are several runestones that help fury re-generation. Your bread and butter Fury generation is obviously going to come from your Fury Generating skills.

### **Fury Generating Abilities:**

**Bash** with **Unleashed** - Generates 7 extra fury per attack.

**Cleave** with **Reaping Swing** - Generates 1 extra fury per enemy hit (max 7)

**Ground Stomp** with **Foot of the Mountain** - Increase Fury gained to 43 fury per stomp.

**War Cry** with **Charge** - Generates 51 fury when used.

**Furious Charge** with **Stamina** - Gains additional 8 fury for every target hit while charging.

**Ancient Spear** with **Skirmish** - Increase Fury gain to 38.

### **Fury Spenders:**

**Battle Rage** with **Into The Fray** - Criticals generate 7 fury per hit.

**Seismic Slam** with **Strength from the Earth** - Reduces the fury cost. (Could be helpful)

**Whirlwind** with **Eye of the Storm** - Reduces the fury cost per second.

### **Situational:**

**Overpower** with **Momentum** - Generates 7 fury per enemy hit.

**Earthquake** with **The Mountains Call** - Reduces fury cost to 40.

### **Passives:**

**Weapons Master** - gives 1 fury per hit with Mighty Weapons

**Animosity** - Increases Fury generation by 10% and maximum Fury is increased by 20.

**Superstition** - Whenever you take damage from a ranged or elemental attack you gain 3 Fury.

**No Escape** - Killing an enemy with Weapon Throw generates 20 fury.

**Unforgiving** - Generates 2 fury per seconds (no degeneration) (This one is awesome)

You can also refer to [this](http://diablo3area.com/diablo3-barbarian-skills.php) link for more skill stats.

[This](http://diablo3buildsguide.com/barbarian-fury-generator-skill-build-analysis/) website may also help you out.